# Filling with zero the missing rows

Tags: r, dataframe

What is the best way to fill in the missing *Duration* value rows with zero for a large data set?

Sample data structure:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Sample data:

```
structure(list(Duration = c(10, 40, 50), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `19:50` = c(1, 3, 2), `21:10` = c(1, 5, 6), `18:10` = c(3, 
    1, 1), `18:20` = c(0, 0, 3), `22:40` = c(1, 2, 1), `20:40` = c(2, 
    2, 2), `20:50` = c(2, 0, 5)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Duration = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `04:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `19:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `21:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `18:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `18:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `22:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `20:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `20:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `complete` to fill the missing sequence and `replace` `NA` to 0 values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  complete(Duration = seq(min(Duration), max(Duration), 10)) %>%
  replace(., is.na(.), 0)

#   Duration `04:00` `19:50` `21:10` `18:10` `18:20` `22:40` `20:40` `20:50`
#     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1       10       0       1       1       3       0       1       2       2
#2       20       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#3       30       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#4       40       0       3       5       1       0       2       2       0
#5       50       0       2       6       1       3       1       2       5
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `merge`

```
out <- merge(
    data.frame(Duration = with(df, seq(min(Duration), max(Duration), 10))),
    df,
    all = TRUE
)
out <- replace(out, is.na(out), 0)
```

gives

```
> out
  Duration 04:00 19:50 21:10 18:10 18:20 22:40 20:40 20:50
1       10     0     1     1     3     0     1     2     2
2       20     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3       30     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4       40     0     3     5     1     0     2     2     0
5       50     0     2     6     1     3     1     2     5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `complete` itself

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    complete(Duration = seq(min(Duration), max(Duration), 10), 
      fill =  setNames(rep(list(0), ncol(.)-1), names(.)[-1]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 9
  Duration `04:00` `19:50` `21:10` `18:10` `18:20` `22:40` `20:40` `20:50`
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1       10       0       1       1       3       0       1       2       2
2       20       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
3       30       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
4       40       0       3       5       1       0       2       2       0
5       50       0       2       6       1       3       1       2       5
```